# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Information Security's [third moderator election](https://security.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: schroeder]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://security.stackexchange.com//users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5590168354422784/0).

Comment: Congrats @schroeder !